# Firebase Relatime Database: Retrieving data from multiple different paths every time a new child is added

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am creating a temperature monitoring app and would like to check the temperature values from several different paths in Firebase Realtime Database. The purpose of app is to monitor the temperature on different devices and generate an alarm.

Below is the code I've written so far. The child_added event is triggered only when a new child is added to the specified path (Device 2). I would like to get the data from multiple paths not just the specified one (Device 2).

Any suggestions?

[image]

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://.firebaseio.com"
});

// Get a database reference to our posts
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("Device 2");

// Retrieve new posts as they are added to our database
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
    var newPost = snapshot.val();
    console.log("Temperature: " + newPost.value);
    
  });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is only targeting the node "Device 2".  It will never receive updates from other devices.

If you want children from "Device 1", you will need to add a whole new query for that node, in addition to the one you're doing for "Device 2".

If you want a single query that receives **all** children from the common root node of devices 1 and 2, then your query should target that root node instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So, if I understand you correctly there is no option to retrieve only the last added value from multiple different paths. You can only retrieve all values under a node?

Comment: Since I'm creating a temperature monitoring app with alarm notifications, requesting all the values under a node every hour wouldn't be the best option for me.

Comment: OK, then just request the ones you want. As I mentioned, you will need a separate query for each of them.